# Current known *lower* bounds to the neutrino masses?

Tags: experimental-physics, mass, neutrinos

I started a little bit of Googling around the topic, and found very few information. There are mainly upper limits. I found lower limits only to the rest mass differences of the different neutrino flavors.

Thus, what are the actually current known lower mass limits to the [neutrino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino) flavors?

Comment: I don't have a reference handy, but I believe you have correctly stated the situation. We know that there are three different neutrino mass states, but we don't know whether the lightest neutrino is massive or massless.

Comment: @rob Thank you. If it is so, then we have a lower limit at least for the second lightest neutrino?

Comment: The differences of the square masses are known (to within a sign in one case). From that you can determine the lower bound on the heaviest mass state, and (modulo knowing the hierarchy) you can place a lower bound on the middle mass state. Beyond that you're stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lower mass limits of neutrinos is not 0eV. They have to have a mass, since we can observe neutrino oscillations. This is something the standard model did not get right. Looking at PDG (2014) the boundaries seem to be 0 < m < 2ev.

Comment: I think SM does not predict a zero neutrino mass, it does not predict neutrino mass et al.

Answer (score -6):

The three masses of the neutrinos are: .04ev/cc, .08 and .12.  These are not limits, up or down, these are the masses.  It should be noted that the differences are the mass states.

Comment: From where do you know it?

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know any experimental result about this. There is an ongoing, \$60million experiment in Karlsruhe, Germany (KATRIN), which will measure the mass of the anti-electron neutrino, if it is over $\approx$ 0.13eV.

Comment: These values don't even respect [the known $\Delta (m^2)$s](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/270752).